# PyCharm intellisense doesnt understand Quartz, how do i expand Intellisense

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I was wanting to make sure intellisense would properly pick up.  When importing Quartz into my project, it doesnt really understand the functions and doesnt give errors, but doesnt understand anything about the function.

Is there a way to give intellisense a greater depth of understanding for the modules I am using.

Comment: Are you sure it should be supported? Is Quartz added to PATH?

Comment: That's what i was curious about.  I know it finds it as a module so i am just working through docs for syntax etc.  I thought it would be nice if it extended accordingly so i didnt have to look up specifics. Thoughts?